# How do I change the resolution/dpi for Galaxy on Fire 2 HD?

Tags: android, galaxy-on-fire-2

For some reason, the game Galaxy on Fire 2 HD for Android is scaling incorrectly on my LG V30. I remember there was a way to change the DPI for a specific game, but can't remember how to do it.

Here's how it looks like: https://snag.gy/ckGqDx.jpg

Here's how it should look like: https://snag.gy/OPX4GA.jpg

My LG V30 has a resolution of 1440 x 2880 pixels, 18:9 ratio (~537 ppi density).

Your help is appreciated.

P.S. I tried reaching out to the publisher/developer via every possible way and I got no response, as if they cared anyway.